How to check which derived class is in use?
Let's say I have this super class:
public class SuperClass { }

And these sub classes:
public class SubClass1 : SuperClass { }
public class SubClass2 : SuperClass { }

We have this client code:
public void DoStuff(SuperClass arg)
{
    if (arg is instance of SubClass1, but not an instance of SubClass2) // How to check this ?
    {
        var data = (SubClass1) arg;
        // Do stuff
    } 
}

How to check if arg is a SubClass1 only or a SubClass2 only ?

You're pretty close: if (arg is not SubClass2 && arg is SubClass1 sc1) { var data = sc1; /* do stuffs ... */ }

by all means favor a solution where you give SuperClass a property that you then override in one or both of the subclasses, and decide based on its value.

Is SubClass2 extending from SuperClass or SubClass1?

Ok, seems to be the right thing to do

SubClass2 is extending SuperClass

Searchterm is "Visitor Pattern".

Can you put that in a [mre]? With the code given, I can't reproduce without intentionally making them all Sub1 instances.

A class cannot be SubClass1 and SubClass2 at the same time. Siblings in a class hierarchy are not assignment compatible. Therefore, you need only one check:
if (arg is SubClass1 data)
{
    // Do stuff with data which is typed as SubClass1 
} 

Note that I am using pattern matching here. The type of the object is tested and if it matches, then it is assigned to the variable data. This automatically declares data as SubClass1.
You can also use pattern matching in a switch statement:
switch (arg)
{
    SubClass1 sub1:
        DoStuff1(sub1);
        break;
    SubClass2 sub2:
        DoStuff2(sub2);
        break;
}

If you need to return a value, then a switch expression is even easier.
string s = arg switch { SubClass1 => "Sub1", SubClass2 => "Sub2", _ "another one" };

Such uses of if or switch are often an indication that a more object-oriented approach might solve the problem better. As an example, let us consider my switch-statement above. Instead of switching on the (sub-)type to decide whether DoStuff1 or DoStuff2 must be executed, we could declare an abstract or virtual method DoStuff in the base class. The sub-classes can then override this method and implement their type-specific stuff. Then, we can simply call arg.DoStuff();.
public abstract class SuperClass
{
    public abstract void DoStuff();
}

public class SubClass1 : SuperClass
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from SubClass1");
    }
}

public class SubClass2 : SuperClass
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from SubClass2");
    }
}

Then
public void DoStuffExample(SuperClass arg)
{
    arg.DoStuff(); // Will print a message according to the runtime type of arg.
}


Given the inheritance hierarchy BaseClass --> SubClass --> SubSubClass, if obj is SubClass, then obj can be a SubClass or a SubSubClass. But note that we have a parent-child relationship here.
But this is okay in most cases, since SubSubClass is assignment compatible to SubClass and can do everything its parent class can do. In OOP you should not have bother about the real type of an object. Example: TextBox, Label and ComboBox all derive (directly or indirectly) from Control. If you have a Control c = Controls[0];, you can safely write c.BackColor = Color.Yellow;.

I already tried that. if (arg is SubClass1 data) ? "SubClass1" : "SubClass2" always returns SubClass1, since arg is a SuperClass reference

The point is to differentiate the two sub classes from a super class reference

Well, this is precisely what my code does. If arg is SubClass1 data returns true, then arg is a SubClass1 and is assigned to data, otherwise it could be either a SubClass (unless SubClass is abstract) or a SubClass2 and data` is undefined.

I was wrong in the way I called the code. I was actually instantiating a SuperClass instance. The only solution in my scenario is to create a new field to store the actual subtype, as advised by @Cee

You could declare SuperClass as abstract, if its instantiation is not desired.

For the ONLY part in your question, you would need to do:
arg.GetType()==typeof(SubClass1)

You can use pattern matching to do the check and assignment all in one go:
if (arg is SubClass1 data)
{
    // Do stuffs, data has already been assigned
}

There is no need to do a separate check for SubClass2 because of the way the classes have been defined.
If you want a seperate check for "is NOT a subclass of any kind" then you can do a comparison using GetType(), as follows:
if (arg.GetType() == typeof(SuperClass))
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a SuperClass (and not a derived type)");
}
else if (arg is SubClass1 data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a SubClass1");
}
else if (arg is SubClass2 data2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It is a SubClass2");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subclass type not supported");
}


I already tried that. if (arg is SubClass1 data) ? "SubClass1" : "SubClass2" always returns SubClass1, since arg is a SuperClass reference

The point is to differentiate the two sub classes from a super class reference

That doesn't make sense @acmoune - if that is what you observe, then there is probably something in your code not shown in the question.

"The point is to differentiate the two sub classes from a super class reference" - See my update.

Try this
public void DoStuff(SuperClass arg)
{
    if (arg is SubClass1 && arg.GetType() == typeof(SubClass1))
    {
        var data = (SubClass1)arg;
        // Do stuff
    }
    else
    {
       // Do other stuff
    }
}


Although the question was already answered (by pattern matching or other options) a different approach could render much better (and maintainable) results:
If your SuperClass declares an abstact method
public class SuperClass {
    public abstract DoStuffMethod();
}

Then your SubClass1 and SubClass2 can do different things
public class SubClass1
    public override DoStuffMethod() {
        //do subclass1 things here
    }
}

public class SubClass2
    public override DoStuffMethod() {
        //do subclass2 things here
    }
}

this will make the subclasses worry about what they have to do, instead of a different class altogether having their logic.
your client code would look much simpler too
public void DoStuff(SuperClass arg)
{
    arg.DoStuffMethod();
}

